# How to use \ split to write an equation on multiple lines in beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to write an equation on several lines in a presentation in the beamer environment.

Thank you

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
&M_{RR| _{G}}.\dot{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{{2}}+{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{{2}}\wedge (M_{RR| _{G}}.{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{{2}})...\\
&...+M_{TT}.V_{G}\wedge\{\dot{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{1}+\dot{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{{2}}\wedge V_{G}\}...\\
&...+M_{TT}.V_{G}\wedge\{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{{2}}\wedge({\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{{2}}\wedge V_{G})+{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{2}\wedge {\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{1}\}=\tau_2
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
\phantom{\hspace{2.0cm}} 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal working example starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, like the following snippet.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A long equation}
\begin{align*}
M_{RR| _{G}}&\cdot\dot{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont
v}_{{2}}+{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{{2}}\wedge (M_{RR|
_{G}}\cdot{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{{2}})\cdots\\
&\cdots+M_{TT}\cdot V_{G}\wedge\{\dot{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont
v}_{1}+\dot{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{{2}}\wedge
V_{G}\}\cdots\\
&\cdots+M_{TT}\cdot V_{G}\wedge\{{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{{2}}\wedge({\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{{2}}\wedge V_{G})+{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{2}\wedge {\fontfamily{lmr}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont v}_{1}\}=\tau_2
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remarks:

- You should not use `...`, but `\dots` or `\cdots`.
- Likewise, `\cdot` looks better than `.` in equations.
- You can simply use `align*` IMHO, and in presentations I'd refrain fro using equation numbers.

Answer (score 3):

- first of all I would remove all clutter in your equation
- for multi line equations the package `amsmath` defines the `multline` environment, however, equation number is aligned with the last equation line
- in your case I suggest to use the `multlined` environment provided by `mathtools` and encapsulate it in `equation`:

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage{mathtools}

      \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{for long equation is used \texttt{multlined} environment}
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{multlined}[0.9\linewidth]
  M_{RR|_{G}}\dot{v}_{2} + v_{2}\wedge (M_{RR|_{G} v_{2}}) \dotsm   \\
  \dotsm +M_{TT}V_{G}\wedge\{\dot{v}_{1}+\dot{v}_{2}\wedge V_{G}\} \dotsm  \\
  \dotsm M_{TT}V_{G}\wedge\{v_{2}\wedge(v_{2}\wedge V_{G}) + v_{2}\wedge v_{1}\} = \tau_2
  \end{multlined}
  \end{equation}
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: @Zarko Please feel free to undo my edit if you don't like it!

Comment: @samcarter, thank you very much for improvement of my answer. writing of explanations is not my strength side :-(